# How to stop VS2008 trying to compile .ASP pages as Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, asp-classic

I have a website with a mix of ASP (classic) and ASP.NET pages.

For some reason Visual Studio (specifically 2008 Pro) keeps trying to compile the ASP classic pages.

***How do I prevent it from trying to compile the .asp pages?***

Reason: I'm getting a ton of errors on a specific .asp file that includes a Class. I believe it's trying to compile it as a Visual Basic class instead of seeing it as a vBScript class. It should be skipping over .asp files anyway, correct?

Here is the error:

> Property Get/Let/Set are no longer
>   supported; use the new Property
>   declaration syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed Service Pack 1? It addresses some issues with classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

What is in the @Page directive on those classic ASP pages? Have you tried inserting `<% @Page language="vbscript" %>` Maybe this does it already?

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution. Go to the file explorer (in windows, not in vs), choose properties and make them hidden. This will stop Visual Studio from compiling the files.